# Wait laps of time between two calls to a webservice using RobotFrameWork

Tags: python, robotframework, wait, sleep, squash

I want to call a webservice and recover a date1 
than I want to wait couple of seconds before calling the same webservice and recover date2

I have tried with the keyWord sleep

```py
${Date1}=   Recuperer Donnee Liste   ${monSubscriberJsonC1}    recepetionDerniereLocalisation

Log   ${Date1}

     \    Sleep 1.5

Log   ${monSubscriberJsonC2}

${Date2}=   Recuperer Donnee Liste   ${monSubscriberJsonC2}    recepetionDerniereLocalisation

Log   ${Date2}
```

As a message I got

```
Keyword name cannot be empty.
```

and also

```
No keyword with name 'Sleep 10s' found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the `Sleep` keyword documentation:
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Sleep

Applied to your given example:

```
${Date1}=   Recuperer Donnee Liste   ${monSubscriberJsonC1}    recepetionDerniereLocalisation

Log   ${Date1}
Sleep  1.5s

Log   ${monSubscriberJsonC2}

${Date2}=   Recuperer Donnee Liste   ${monSubscriberJsonC2}    recepetionDerniereLocalisation

Log   ${Date2}
```

It's always good to write the unit after sleep times. As you see from the documentation it's also possible to sleep milliseconds `ms` which is often the default when dealing with time, unlike in Robot where the default is a second.

Answer (score 3):

This `No keyword with name 'Sleep 10s' found.` occurs because you don't have the minimun two spaces between keyword (`Sleep`) and argument(s) (`10s`). Add a space between them.

Also, `\` is used for loop indendation.